# How do I add a custom block to the very top of every page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-community, promotional-banner

I have been searching for hours on this topic and did not find any comprehensive answers.

I want to display a block at the **very top** of every page. Ideally, this block's content would be editable from the Magento 2 interface (e.g. in **Content > Elements > Blocks**).

This block would be used for sales promotions etc.

This is for a (minimally) customized version of the Luma theme.

Answer (score 4):

We should use Widget: **CONTENT > Widgets** > Create a new widget with our custom static block, in **Layout Updates**, should choose **Display on - All Pages**

[image: Widget Layout Updates]